# Execute Third-Party Jar From Command Line, Flag To Ignore SSL Issues?

Tags: java, command-line, jar

I'm executing the W3C CSS validator jar from the command line, built from the latest-available source. Exceptions are raised when the jar requests some HTTPS urls.

Some HTTPS urls are fine, others are not. Of those that cause exceptions to be raised of which I am aware (just one), the SSL cert appears to be fine when requesting the relevant URL in Chrome.

I call the CSS validator as follows:

```
java -jar css-validator.jar "https://example.com/"
```

And get the following error output:

```
javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Server key
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.throwSSLException(Handshaker.java:1274)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:223)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:868)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:804)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1032)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1328)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1355)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.afterConnect(HttpsClient.java:515)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:185)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:153)
    at org.w3c.css.util.HTTPURL.getConnection(HTTPURL.java:257)
    at org.w3c.css.util.HTTPURL.getConnection(HTTPURL.java:312)
    at org.w3c.css.css.DocumentParser.<init>(DocumentParser.java:124)
    at org.w3c.css.css.CssValidator.main(CssValidator.java:154)
Caused by: java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: Could not create EC public key
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11ECKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(P11ECKeyFactory.java:169)
    at java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:334)
    at sun.security.ssl.HandshakeMessage$ECDH_ServerKeyExchange.<init>(HandshakeMessage.java:1057)
    at sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:218)
    ... 13 more
Caused by: sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11Exception: CKR_DOMAIN_PARAMS_INVALID
    at sun.security.pkcs11.wrapper.PKCS11.C_CreateObject(Native Method)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11ECKeyFactory.generatePublic(P11ECKeyFactory.java:233)
    at sun.security.pkcs11.P11ECKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(P11ECKeyFactory.java:164)
    ... 16 more
```

I'd ideally like to ignore absolutely all such SSL errors that could be raised when executing this jar from the command line using something along the lines of:

```
java -ignore-all-of-these-ssl-errors-please -jar css-validator.jar "https://example.com/"
```

Clearly `ignore-all-of-these-ssl-errors-please` is not a valid command line flag.

Is there a flag that will do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not possible. It's that way for a reason, and that reason is to prevent you from writing code that someone else implicitly trusts to ensure that the SSL session is secure and genuine.  The reason it works in Chrome and not from Java is that Java comes with a very sparse set of root CAs.

The only way around this if you don't control the code is to add the necessary CA certificates to the local keystore.  I believe you can export Chrome's CAs in a form you can import into the keystore.